# Remove additional date from notification and lock screen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-8, date-and-time

In my Samsung Galaxy S8, Android 9, I see an additional date, showing in parentheses, both on the lock screen and in the notification bar when I roll it down. For example, right now it says "16:58 Mon, April 8 (FAR 19)".
I'm attaching a screenshot of the lock screen, but it also appears in the notification bar.

[image]

I checked within all the apps I could think of, also looked to see that I don't have any "other calendar" or "alternative calendar" configured. Also, I found out that FAR is a Persian calendar which makes no sense for me...

Tried already contacting Samsung chat support but the couldn't help (they did ask me to reset my phone configuration and to clear caches and other stuff).

Comment: Can you try what is suggested here: https://www.sammobile.com/forum/threads/37711-How-to-change-G955F-CSCcode-to-simcard-code-for-your-OXM-country?p=193910&viewfull=1#post193910 ?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio that means resetting my device to factory defaults? that's the last thing I want to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it's not something that can be changed via settings - it come's like that out of the box when the device is meant to be sold in a different market.

In my case, every time I insert a new SIM card into the phone and restart it I got a notification saying that in order to set new settings for the phone I must do a factory reset. So when putting back my own SIM I also got this message. Once I did that suggested factory reset phone started fresh with a factory configuration that matches my region, making the Persian calendar disappear and also *enabling other features that weren't enabled before, such as native call recording*

(worked on both Samsung Galaxy S8 and S20)